# Postgres - Is it possible to have a `UNIQUE INDEX` with `NULLS NOT DISTINCT`?

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

Given this table definition with a partial index:

```sql
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE user_note (
  user_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  item_id VARCHAR,
  note VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  archived_at TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX active_note
    ON user_note(user_id, item_id)
 WHERE archived_at IS NULL;

END;
```

I would like to ensure there is only one value of `(user_id, item_id)` where the record has not been archived. This constraint should not apply to records with `archived_at` as a non null value (i.e. we should allow many archived records for a given `(user_id, item_id)` pairing).

The above constraint works as intended when `user_id` and `item_id` are both specified:

```sql
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO user_note (user_id, item_id, note) VALUES ('user_1', 'item_1', 'A general note');
INSERT INTO user_note (user_id, item_id, note) VALUES ('user_1', 'item_1', 'A different note');
END;
```

Gives the following error:

```
BEGIN
INSERT 0 1
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "active_note"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, item_id)=(user_1, item_1) already exists.
make: *** [populate] Error 1
```

But allows multiple records with `line_id` of `NULL`:

```sql
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO user_note (user_id, note) VALUES ('user_1', 'A general note');
INSERT INTO user_note (user_id, note) VALUES ('user_1', 'A different note');
END;
```

Output:

```
BEGIN
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
COMMIT
```

I have also tried with a unique index with nulls not distinct like so:

```sql
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE user_note (
  user_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  item_id VARCHAR,
  note VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  archived_at TIMESTAMP,

  UNIQUE NULLS NOT DISTINCT (user_id, item_id)
);

END;
```

But this of course does not take into account the `archived_at` value:

```sql
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO user_note (user_id, note, archived_at) VALUES ('user_1', 'A general note', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO user_note (user_id, note, archived_at) VALUES ('user_1', 'A different note', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END;
```

And I get this unwanted error:

```
BEGIN
INSERT 0 1
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_note_user_id_item_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, item_id)=(user_1, null) already exists.
make: *** [populate] Error 1
```

Is there a way to disallow multiple entries for `(user_id, item_id)` when `archived_at` is `NULL` but to allow when `archived_at` is not `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify a string that cannot occur in `item_id`, for example `'@@@'`. Then create your unique index like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON user_note (
   user_id,
   coalesce(item_id, '@@@')
) WHERE archived_at IS NULL;
```